# How do I switch over between 2 AC power supplies with circuit breakers

Tags: circuit-design, mains, switching, generator

I once saw a diagram where a house was supplied by a generator or from the grid by using 3 trip switches only.

It must be manual so I can select as preferred, and not a automatic system.

I also prefer circuit breakers over a common 3-stage switch-over because the setup can also be used in other applications.

Comment: First and foremost you want the solution to be safe and legal. Unless you're in a position where you can ensure this, I'd suggest you go with the 'common' solution. As well, you don't mention which part of the world you are in - mains voltages, systems and laws differ.

Comment: `How do I switch over between 2 AC power supplies with circuit breakers` ... what does this say? ... you want to use circuit brakers to do the switching or the power supplies have circuit breakers?

Comment: A or B transfer switch using 200A contractors might work.

Comment: 200A contractor? Yea, we have one in our neighborhood.

Comment: let me rephrase. 2 powersources to be switched by using circuit breakers

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the already given comment should be taken more seriously than you think. The switching system must obey local code for mains AC supply systems and also everything that the building owner and the mains AC supplier wants. Building your own version and using it in secrecy is very likely criminal and it will also be a high risk for fire and other serious damages if you are not a competent designer & electrician. I doubt you are not because this question is written.

Ask the local mains AC supplier what to do.

Pure technical problems that a beginner do not easily spot

- the ability to break circuits in all cases without burning arcs in the switches
- preventing in all cases accidental connection between the generator and the external supply, a human must have no way to turn something in wrong order
- making sure that no equipment get too fast new unsynchronized voltage so that a high current switching transient is caused. A running motor must be stopped before an unsynchronized new source can be connected.
- preventing too high load for the generator - if too many high current devices are started at the same time the cumulated starting transients can be to much for the generator. The high current loads should be switched on one by one

In theory the generator could be synced with the grid if you have the grid voltage ON and the generator has the needed circuits. The grid defines its phase angle as it likes.

Comment: you are so right. (if you are not a competent designer & electrician.) Though im entusiast and keep my litle book with things to do like having my gardenlights running of a solar system.

Comment: If you have something that can be seen as a single device which must have 2 alternative power sources with manual selection and there's no running motors consider to swap a plug from one outlet to another.

Answer (score 1):

This is commonly done using an interlock which physically prevents turning on the both the "grid" source and "generator" source breakers at the same time.

The interlock is often a metal or plastic "card" that is fixed to the face of the breaker panel in a way that allows sliding between two positions
so that it blocks one set of breakers or the other allowing the operation of only set one at a time.

Search "generator interlock" for examples.

Comment: Thanx. im looking for alternatives to a interlock

Comment: the only alternative is a transfer switch,  which is the three way switch you mentioned in your question.